# go back to previous webpage with dynamic content

Tags: php, javascript

I have developed 2 webpages:
- page 1 with dynamic content - adding or removing forms by means of buttons+javascript functions + submit button for all created forms. After successful submission of data in the forms a php file redirects to page 2:
- page 2 with a go-back-to-page-1 button (using window.history.go(-1) javascript function)

When going back from page 2 to page 1 the dynamically created forms seem to be lost (e.g, the original page 1 without dynamic content is viewed) which is not meant to happen.

How to keep the forms when going back to page 1? (i noticed a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220024/back-button-for-dynamic-textbox-generation-page-in-php-using-sesison, but without any answers).

Please your suggestions.

Comment: if you submit it will clear everything out...

Comment: simple & cheap solution: Don't `window.history.go(-1)`, instead use `window.location.href=page2`!

Comment: Can you check if Internet Explorer (IE) returns a "Page Has Expired" warning when you use the back button or `window.history.go(-1)`?

Answer (score 1):

you should use only one page and process your data in ajax.
Page 1 = one div and Page 2 = one another div
play with attribute display (and with effect if you want)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page1">
page 1
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txt1"><br>
    <button onclick="savePage1();" type="button">Page 2 ></button>
</form>
</div>
<div id="page2" style="display:none;">
page 2

<button onclick="backPage1();" type="button">< Page 1</button>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function savePage1() {
    // php processing
    /*$.ajax({
      url: "/savePage1.php",
      data: {
        data1: $('#txt1').val()
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        // ...
      }
    });*/

    // insert code into success
    $('#page1').hide();
    $('#page2').show();
}
function backPage1() {  
    $('#page2').hide();
    $('#page1').show();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your answer, but maybe I did not explain well enough the context: I do want to have page 2 as well, it's just a following page after page 1 with other forms. If the user is at page 2 and decides to change the input in page 1 he/she can go back. I could use AJAX for page 1 (once I master that;-)) but will that solve the problem (keep the submitted content at page 1) when i go back from page 2 to 1?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments and code (!) Your concept with the 2 pages is not exactly what i want to achieve but I did pick up your idea with hide and show (instead of creating webpage 1 with forms that are dynamically created page 1 now uses static forms + hide/show + select buttons. Hide and show status still seems to go lost when going to page 2 and back, but the submitted form information is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, dynamic content (or any changes, made dynamically) will be lost when page will be reloaded (or user will move from page and that return) if you didn't make functionality for restoring. In fact, some browsers can save content of form inputs if page was just refreshed, but you definitely shouldn't depend on this.

So for restoring that dynamic changes you must make your own handlers. Just save in session submited content and fill page 1 with data.

You didn't specify all your "dynamic" functionality, so I cannot tell you the best way of automatisation of this process. For basic needs google for "population forms js".